# Where are cmd.exe's settings in registry in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-registry, cmd.exe

In the times of Windows 7, I remember, there was `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\%SystemRoot%_system32_cmd.exe]` where all `cmd.exe` settings were stored. If I deleted this path, all `cmd.exe` would reset to defaults.

In Windows 10 if I delete `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\%SystemRoot%_system32_cmd.exe]`, real user settings of `cmd.exe` won't reset to defaults. I guess there is another place where those settings are stored in registry. How could I find it?

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for this:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor
```

Go to that registry key and delete all the values. Restart and the command prompt resets to default settings.

Comment: this path `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor ` is not available anymore

Answer (score 3):

From my experiments (Windows 10 Version 1809)

1. Defaults are stored in the registry at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console`. These get applied whenever you make a new shortcut or open `cmd.exe` directly (typically from `C:\Windows\System32`), such as from the `Run` window (`Windows Key + R`).
2. If you make any changes to the cmd window while opening it directly (not from a shortcut), these changed settings get saved in `HKCU\Console\%SystemRoot%_system32_cmd.exe`. These override the defaults in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console`.
3. Changed settings for shortcuts are saved within the `.lnk` file itself. This includes the entry in the start menu named `Command Prompt`, which points to the file `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\System Tools\Command Prompt.lnk`. These override the defaults in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console`.

3 seems to be the only difference from Windows 7, which stored shortcut settings in the registry under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\<name_of_shortcut>`

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have the folder `Command Processor` on `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\` you can just create one with this script on PowerShell:

```
$regPath = 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor'

if (! (test-path $regPath) ) {
   write-output "$regPath does not exist, creating"
   $eatMe = new-item -path $regPath
}
```